# Can't get custom dialog to work with DirtyForms

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-dirtyforms

I am using [DirtyForms](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms) and the plugin's base functionality is working. The browser throws a confirmation dialog when the user tries to navigate away from a page.

We use jQuery UI's Dialog for modal confirmations, and I am trying to get this to work with DirtyForms, which has an example directly referring to jQuery UI dialogs. I am using the example directly from their page to set the custom dialog, but it is not using the jQuery Dialog, it still uses the browser's native dialog:

```
$.DirtyForms.dialog = {
    selector: '#unsavedChanges',
    fire: function(message, dlgTitle) {
        $('#unsavedChanges').dialog({title: dlgTitle, width: 350, modal: true});
        $('#unsavedChanges').html(message);
    },
    bind: function() {
        $('#unsavedChanges').dialog('option', 'buttons',
            [
                {
                    text: "Stay Here",
                    click: function(e) {
                        $.DirtyForms.choiceContinue = false;
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: "Leave This Page",
                    click: function(e) {
                        $.DirtyForms.choiceContinue = true;
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            ] 
        ).bind('dialogclose', function(e) {
            // Execute the choice after the modal dialog closes
            $.DirtyForms.choiceCommit(e);
        });
    },
    refire: function(content) {
        return false;
    },
    stash: function() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

With the plugin's debugging turned on, I receive no errors (or any other JS errors), but the modal dialog doesn't fire, only the browser's native one. Other implemented jQuery UI Dialogs on the same page work. I'm not sure what I may be missing here. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where you able to solve this we are running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue is that you don't have a `div` tag in your HTML markup with the id `unsavedChanges`. So, you should add either the HTML...

```
<div id="unsavedChanges" style="display:none;" />
```

or the equivalent in JavaScript...

```
var $dlg = $('<div id="unsavedChanges" style="display:none;" />'); 
$('body').append($dlg);
```

If that is not the issue, I suggest you edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), either by posting an entire HTML document or by using a service such as [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

> **NOTE:** The custom dialog only works when a user clicks a hyperlink in the page. When the user interacts with the browser's navigation, the browser's dialog (if any) is shown. This is because there is no way to override the browser's default navigation behavior with a custom dialog.
>
> In version 2.x it is now possible to [customize the event binding](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms#event-handler-customization), so you can add elements other than hyperlinks if clicking them navigates away from the current page.